# Two events A,B. Given $P(B)$, $P(A|B)$, and $P(B^{c}|A^{c})$, need to find P(B|A)

Tags: probability

This is one of the test questions I am trying to solve:

I am given values for  $P(B)$, $P(A|B)$, and $P(B^{c}|A^{^{c})$.

Now, I need to find $P(B|A)$

In order to find $P(B|A)$, I need to know $P(A)$ because I can find $P(A\cap B)$ from given  $P(B)$, $P(A|B)$.

However, when I worked on expanding $P(A\cap B)$, all I can get is this far:

$$P(B^{c}|A^{c})=\frac{P(B^{c}\cap A^{c})}{P(A^{c})}=\frac{P((B\cup A)^{c})}{P(A^{c})}==\frac{1-P(B\cup A)}{P(A^{c})}$$.

In order to get an expression for $P(A\cup B)$, I need $P(A^{c})$, but $P(A^{c})$ is not given nor am I able to derive from any given conditions. Even if I can get $P(A\cup B)$, I stil have no idea getting $P(A\cap B)$ from there.  Please tell me what I should proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from where you left off we have $$P(B^{c}|A^{c})=\frac  {1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A \cap B)} {1-P(A)}.$$ Multiply both sides by $1-P(A)$ an write the equation as $$P(A)[1-P(B^{c}|A^{c})]=1-P(B)+P(A \cap B)-P(B^{c}|A^{c}).$$ Now divide by $1-P(B^{c}|A^{c})$ to get the value of $P(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting close.  Let me introduce some notation for the things you know:

$$x = P(B), \quad y = P(A | B), \quad z = P(B^c | A^c)$$

As you observed, $P(A \cap B) = xy$, so to compute $P(B | A)$ you just need $P(A)$.

Continuing on from your formula for $z$, we just need to introduce two tools:

- $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A)$
- The inclusion-exclusion principle: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Putting it all together:

$$z = \frac{1 - P(A) - x - xy}{ 1 - P(A)}$$

Now with a little algebra you can solve for $P(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

First as $\ P(A/B) $ is given we can find $\ P(A∩B) $ and then as you said $$\ P(B^c|A^c)=1−P(B∪A)/P(A^c) $$
and we know that $\ p(A^c) $ is $\ 1-p(A) $ ,and substituting this in above equation we can find the relation between $$p(A)\space \text{and}\space P(B∪A) \to 1 $$
we can show by venn diagram that $$\ P(B∪A)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A∩B) \to 2 $$
Now we know $\ P(A∩B) $ ,and two relations between $\ P(A) and P(B∪A) $ (those are 1 and 2) and from those we can find P(A) which inturn gives us $$\ P(B|A)=P(A∩B)/P(A) $$
Hope that helps!